# How to put a character at the end of line of text in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Long Text and want to put a character at the end of the lines! 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the replace dialog box up (Ctrl-H),

unfortunately there's no option to choose 'regular expressions'. If there were you'd put $ in the find, and whatever in the replace.  $ represents the end of the line in regex. But word doesn't support that

Type ^p in the find section. Then whatever in the 'replace' section. I knew that 'cos I remembered from some time back.  That does it.

You can choose it from the special menu.  click 'special' in the find and replace dialog box. Then It's right at the very top of that menu. Not line break or paragraph character. it's called paragraph mark.

NOTE- in your case, in the replace field, you'll want text followed by ^p.

[image]

[image]

The other type of new line, is a manual line break. You type into your document a shift-enter and you get a good old fashioned new line. And to replace it you do ^l or 'manual line break' in the find and replace dialog box.